# Looping 3D-ish AS3 Image Gallery

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image-gallery

Hi I want setup a gallery with an effect similar to this: http://www.alva-amco.com/, but I wanted the buttons items to endlessly loop instead of stopping and the beginning and end of the data. I understand how to do it when the images are just in a row moving along a straight line but this extra motion is throwing me off. Also, the I'm not sure how to program the individual buttons to be clickable so that the gallery redraws itself correctly as it jumps to  a new index.

Any explanation, links, or code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop endlessly, you just need to implement the looping behavior manually by going back to the start on the final frame.  Note that your start and end frames would have to be identical in this case, or (in the case of a continuous animation) represent a smooth transition from the end frame to the start frame.

Take, for example, a simple, looping animation - a circle ranslating from the left to the right side of the screen.  Once it has crossed the screen, it moves back to its starting point.  The animation is smooth such that the last frame transitions to start frame flawlessly:

```
a           b
x x x x x x x
```

The "x" is the circle, and "a" and "b" are the start and end frames, respectively.  Imagine that the screen were very small.  Now if the circle moves 10 pixels each frame, and its x position on frame "a" is 20, then its x position on frame "b" would have to be 10 in order to present the illusion of a smooth, continuous animation to the user.  On frame "b" you would need the code:

```
gotoAndPlay('a');
```

If the animation is non-continuous, meaning it is a stop-start animation, as in the case you described, then the circle's position on frames "a" and "b" would have to be identical.

And so specific to the menu in the site you're referring to, frame "a" would have the following buttons:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

whereas frame "b - 1" would have the following buttons:

```
8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

(where the "1" in "b-1" is however many frames are in your animation from one button to another)

and frame "b" would be identical to frame "a".

Now, to program the buttons to animate correctly to bring the clicked button to the forefront, you could do something like this:

```
var is_transitioning:Boolean = false;

// For each button...
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, animate_menu_on_button_click);

function animate_menu_on_button_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   if (is_transitioning) 
     return;

   is_transitioning = true;

   var target_button:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
   var end_frame:uint = get_end_frame_by_button(target_button);

   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void
   {
      if (menu.currentFrame == end_frame)
      {
        menu.stop();
        stage.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
        is_transitioning = false;
      }
   });

   menu.play();
}

// Note that the end frame is the frame where the button is in 'focus' (at the forefront)
function get_end_frame_by_button(target_button:DisplayObject):uint
{
   switch (target_button)
   {
      case 'button_one':
      // etc.
   }
}
```

\m/\m/

Answer (score 0):

I have one link where you can find many components for creating gallery. you just need to download that its free. and just need to change in XML and images.

You can find link [here](http://www.flashxml.net).

Have a NICE DAY